# Expecting Identifier Error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am converting Javascript to C# in Unity and I got this error. I do not how to solve it. I do not know a lot about Javascript or C#.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraSwitch2 : MonoBehaviour {
    public UnityEngine.Camera FirstCamera;
    public UnityEngine.Camera SecondCamera;

    void  Update ()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("f")) 
        {
            FirstCamera.GetComponent.<Camera>().enabled = false;
            SecondCamera.GetComponent.<Camera>().enabled = true;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
        {
            FirstCamera.GetComponent.<Camera>().enabled = true;
            SecondCamera.GetComponent.<Camera>().enabled = false;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what error is that?  What line does it occur on?  Please [edit] your question to contain as much information about the error as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing GetComponent is wrong.

```
FirstCamera.GetComponent.<Camera>().enabled = true;
```

instead you should do it like this

```
FirstCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
```

There is no dot after GetComponent instead inequality signs with the object or class you want get.

["Unity GetComponent scripting"](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

Here is the correction to the code :

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("f")) 
    {
        FirstCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
        SecondCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
    {
        FirstCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
        SecondCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;   
    }
```

Also

```
public UnityEngine.Camera FirstCamera;
public UnityEngine.Camera SecondCamera;
```

in the above two variable declaration case you don't need to declare them using UnityEngine.Camera rather you can directly declare them as

```
public Camera FirstCamera;
public Camera SecondCamera;
```

Because you have already defined the **UnityEngine** namespace at the very top of the file so you don't need to use it while referring to the classes of that namespace.